# ¿Cómo crear un método para agregar valores a un arreglo de enteros en Java?

Tags: java, array

Quiero que mi método reciba un solo parámetro (el número que quiero agregar a mi arreglo) y que se agregue una sola vez ya que el método que construí agrega el valor a todos los lugares del arreglo.
Para que cuando se use el método otra vez solamente llene una vez un lugar vacío

Comment: Para entender mejor la pregunta agrega codigo. Te invito a lee **[mcve]**

Comment: Se necesita algo mas de info para ayudarte. El arreglo esta vacío? la inserción es al final? tienes algo del codigo ya hecho?

Comment: lic void agregar(int dato) {  for ( int i = 0; i < datos.length;i++){ if (i< datos.length){ datos[i]= dato } else { System.out.println( "El arreglo esta lleno") } Si, esta vacío. No, osea tego una archivo de prueba y en el se usa el metodo 5 veces para agregar los 5 datos metidos en un olo arreglo, pero con el metodo que ya tengo me gresa el mismo dato en todos los lugares.

Comment: @SúbditodeMike agrega el codigo que hicistes a tu pregunta!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Prueba con algo como esto. Estoy asumiendo que quieres insertar en un espacio del arreglo que esté vacio:

```
 public void agregar(int dato) { 
     bool flag = true; 
     for ( int i = 0; i < datos.length;i++){ 
          if (estaVacio(datos[i]) ){ //Verifica si la posición en el arreglo esta vacía.
               datos[i]= dato;
               flag = false;
               break; 
          } 
     }
     if(flag){ //Si el flag es verdadero significa que esta lleno
           System.out.println( "El arreglo esta lleno") 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Gracias, te amo.

Comment: no se deben contestar preguntas que no han demostrado que no se ha intentado algo, trata de evitarlo la proxima vez (y asi no te llenas de negativos)